# How to Get an existing Windows XP Mode Virtual Machine on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a new computer with Windows 8.1 From my old PC with Windows 7 I have a folder with "Windows XP Mode.vhd" file ~120GB. I want to run this VM on my new Windows 8.1

Is any way to do it ?

**UPDATED**

I can't import my vhd file into VirtualBox with a following error:

[image]

Comment: You should export the VM from you XP machine before trying to load it into a new machine.

Comment: maybe exporting will see to the xml file too

Comment: the old XP mode VHD is a diff file, which uses a base VHD from C:\Program Files. without this file, you can't open the VHD.